# How to transfer range() output into string

Tags: python

How to create a `list` of `string` using `range()` built-in function in python?

`range(1,7)` produces a range object equivilant to `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

Desired list: `['1','2','3','4','5','6']`

Comment: `range(7)` does not output `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`.

Comment: It doesn't even output a list ;)

Comment: If you mark it as duplicate you should link to a duplicate

Comment: The link is above the question

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000, it does in python 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a cast to `str()` & [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) as per the following:

```
string_list = [str(x) for x in range(1, 7)]
```

Comment: you want range(1, 7) since OP wants the list to start at '1'.

Answer (score 4):

With the map function:

```
list(map(str,range(7)))
```

Comment: Or `[*map(str,range(7))]`. But your solution is much more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Or the new f-strings:

```
>>> [f'{i}' for i in range(7)]
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

Comment: Note this is python 3.6+

Answer (score 1):

Use string formatting & list comprehension as per the following

`string_list = ["{}".format(x) for x in range(1,7)]`

Comment: You don't need the full functionality of `str.format` here - `str(x)` would have worked just as well as `"{}".format(x)`. Also, if you wanted to start from 1, your `range` call is wrong.

Comment: Even if you need a format spec (which you don't, since you aren't using one), you still wouldn't want to use `str.format` here; just call `format(x, "03")` instead of `"{:03}".format(x)`. You only need `str.format` to put multiple things together. And even then, f-strings are usually better: `f"{x:03}"`.

Comment: @user2357112, I have fixed the `range` call. and you are right about the use of `str(x)` it is also a solution